# What's the easiest way to add TLS to a Kubernetes service?

Tags: kubernetes, lets-encrypt, kubernetes-ingress

I have a simple web server exposed publicly on Kubernetes on GKE and a domain registered. I'm looking to add TLS to this so it's accessible via HTTPS. I've heard a lot about using Let's Encrypt and ended up attempting this: https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/blob/master/docs/tutorials/acme/quick-start/index.rst but found it totally over-whelming. Is there a simpler approach to using Let's Encrypt given that my deployment is just a single service and pod?

The config I'm using is:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web
  labels:
    app: web
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: web
        image: gcr.io/my-repo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
        readinessProbe:
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-balancer-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    run: web
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress-app

spec:
  rules:
  - host: my.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: web-balancer-service
          servicePort: 8080
```

========================================

EDIT: Following @Utku Özdemir's suggestion I tried to codify those changes into YAML. I created the IP address with

```
gcloud compute addresses create example-ip-address --global
```

And the certificate and provisioning with: https://gist.github.com/nickponline/ab74d3d179e21474551b7596c6478eea

Everything provisions correctly but when I inspect the ManagedCertificates with `kubectl describe ManagedCertificates example-certificate` is says

```
Spec:
  Domains:
    app.domain.xyz
Status:
  Certificate Name:    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  Certificate Status:  Provisioning
  Domain Status:
    Domain:  app.domain
    Status:  FailedNotVisible
Events:      <none>
```

I've waited 24 hours so assume that this isn't going to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use the ingress controller of the GKE itself, when you create an *Ingress* resource, it triggers the creation of a *Load Balancer* resource in the Google Cloud Platform. Normally, SSL termination is a responsibility of the ingress controller, therefore that GCP load balancer is responsible of doing the SSL termination.

This means, cert-manager will not work for your case, since the certificates will live outside of your cluster, and the traffic **will be already SSL terminated** before coming in your cluster.

Luckily, GCP has self-provisioned SSL (Let's Encrypt) support. To make use of that, yo need to follow the steps below:

1. Go to the Load Balancing screen on GCP, switch to advanced view, and jump to the Certificates tab (or simply click [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/net-services/loadbalancing/advanced/sslCertificates/list)).
2. Create a new SSL certificate, with "Create Google-managed certificate" chosen. To the domain field, write down the exact domain you want the SSL certificate for. It should look like this:

[image]

3. Go to the [External IP Addresses](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/addresses/list) screen, and reserve a new static IP address. Choose the type to be global (at the time of writing, GCP ingress controller only supports global IP addresses). Should look like this:

[image]

4. Take the static IP that you reserved (in this example it is `34.95.84.106`)

[image]

Go to your domain registrar, and add an `A` type record for your domain (the one in the SSL certificate) to point to the static IP you allocated. In this example, it would be `my-app.example.com -> 34.95.84.106`.

5. Finally, you will need to edit your ingress to put 2 annotations, so it will hint the Google Cloud's Ingress Controller to use the static IP you reserved, and the certificate you created. See the ingress example below:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress-app
  annotations:
    ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: my-ssl-certificate # the name of the SSL certificate resource you created
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: my-static-ip # the name of the static ip resource you created
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false" # if you want to block plain http
spec:
  rules:
    - host: my-app.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: web-balancer-service
              servicePort: 8080
```

Apply it, and verify that the changes are reflected by going to the Load Balancers screen on GCP.

#### Important Notes:

- If there already is a GCP Load Balancer that is created by an Ingress, the **changes you do (annotations) on the ingress will not reflect to the existing load balancer**. Therefore, delete your existing ingress, make sure the existing load-balancer disappears, and create the ingress with correct annotations, so the load balancer will be configured correctly.
- For the Let's Encrypt provisioning to work, your DNS record should be in place. It checks the owner of the domain using DNS before issuing the certificate. Also, the initial **provisioning can take quite some time** (up to half an hour).

Comment: Thank you @Utku Özdemir for the suggestion, I tried to codify these steps. (See my edit to the original question). Have I done that correctly?

Comment: Great to hear that. In the way I described there is no cert-manager deployment involved. You can safely delete it.